Power failure or bug?
It looks like my power adapter or cable or something else (?) is failing.  But it's a bit weird.  When I plug in my 2019 Macbook Pro, several times I hear the "just plugged in" sound.  What's weird is that the display dims when that setting is turned OFF.  Also, if the issue is the adapter or the cable, is that it only happens for the first minute after plugging in.  Happens then no matter how still I sit, and is not triggered later by movement.
Could that be a problem with the internal USB components?

Hearing the power chime several times means the connection is making and breaking. Could be dirty connectors; could be a loose connection; could be the socket. Start by testing another cable/power brick at an Apple Store.

No Apple store for 400 kilometers.  But I can get another cable a kilometer away.  Don't suspect the socket; happens on both sides.  Also, USB peripherals have no problem in any of the four sockets.  Cable is a maybe, but the timing issue and movement issue makes that iffy.  Anyway, I need to get another cable anyway.

Another cable seemed to fix it.  But it started doing it even more after about a week.  And why would the display dim when the settings say not to?

If you've ruled out everything outside of the laptop, then it's something inside the laptop. Hardware problems need hands-on, visual inspection and testing.

@benwiggy, yes, I'm afraid I need to do a full hardware diagnosis.  On the other hand, it could be that this new cable is poor quality.  Most are, even those from Apple.

I'd expect a brand new cable to either "work" or "not work" (and it should work out of the box) so "quality" is limited to durability, resilience, etc after time/use.. Maybe test the cable with some other appliance. But if it fails with two cables, then my money's on the laptop itself.

I have no other equipment that requires USB-C on both ends.  Some of the symptoms seem to me to indicate the laptop, but for the trouble to go away for a week with a new cable …
